# Golang mock for all arguments except

Tags: go

```
mock.on("FunctionName", "someStringArgument").Return(...)
```

Suppose if `someStringArgument` is "hello" then I want to return "1". But if `someStringArgument` is any other string I want to return "2".

How is this achieve able with GoMock?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the mock library you're using

Comment: @Jesse, https://godoc.org/github.com/golang/mock/gomock

Comment: https://godoc.org/github.com/golang/mock/gomock#Call.DoAndReturn. That being said, you can always just write a mock implementation yourself if you need something very specific to happen. Nothing forces you to always use the generated mocks.

Comment: What have you tried? Include your code. What problems did you encounter?

Comment: It's dead simple: Don't mock.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is write a custom function which will return your desired output.

Here is a simple example of what I do.

Define a custom response function

```
func FunctionNameResponse(arg String) string{
    if arg == "hellp" {
        // I used quotes because you mentioned "1" and not 1
        return "1"
    }
    return "2"
}
```

Call custom function anywhere needed.

```
mock.on("FunctionName", mock.Anything).Return(FunctionNameResponse("someStringArgument"))
```